# How can I return to the top of the script in python?

Tags: python

I have a script in python that consists of multiple list of functions, and at every end of a list I want to put a back function that will let me return to the beginning of the script and choose another list. for example:

```
list = ("1. List of all users",
    "2. List of all groups",
    "3. Reset password",
    "4. Create new user",
    "5. Create new group",
    "6. List all kernel drivers",
    "7. List all mounts",
    "8. Mount a folder",
    "9. Exit")
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

And if I choose 1 another list opens:

```
list = "1) Show user Groups \n2) Show user ID \n3) Show user aliases  \n4) Add new aliases \n5) Change password \n6) Back"
print
print list
```

A more specific example.

Comment: Use some kind of loop. You can learn how to do that here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop until user explicitly doesnt exits you program.

```
import os



def show_users():
    print("1) show group user")
    print("2) go back")

    i = int(input())
    if i==1:
        pass    # do something
    elif i==2:
        show_list()

def show_list():
    print("1) list of all users")
    print("2) exit")
    i = int(input())

    if i ==1:
        show_users()
    elif i==2:
        exit(0)


while True:
    show_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a while loop, it just keeps running through these options until you answer 4 to the first question. You can place one while loop somewhere in the other to make it all much more complicated.

```
keepGoing = True
while keepGoing:
  choice1 = raw_input('first answer')
  if choice1 == '1':
    choice2 = raw_input('second answer')
    if choice2 == '1':
      print('1 again')
    else:
      print('something different')
  if choice1 == '2':
    print('two')
  if choice1 == 3:
    print('three')
  if choice1 == 4:
    keepGoing = False
```